# jQuery doesn't seem to recognize a different string with an Ajax call statuscode 403

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http-headers, http-status-code-403

I am having a funny situation which I am not sure if it is my fault, or jQuery's fault, and therefore I would like to consult you guys.

Currently I am doing an Ajax call, which returns a 403 status code. But the string accompanying that 403 is different from the standard.

It returns `403 access denied` but according to specification it should be `403 Forbidden`.

I know how to get a 200 statuscode from the server, the question is more in how to handle this situation.

This is my Ajax jQuery code, and it does not get in any of the `console.log()` situations.

```
this.get = function(){
    var callUrl = self.url + "&limit=" + self.limit + "&page=" + self.page;
    callUrl += self.getFilterQuery();
    callUrl += "&callback=?";
    console.log(callUrl);
    $.ajax({
        url: callUrl,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        },
        statusCode: {
            403: function(response){
                console.log('error');
                console.log(response);
            }
        },
        error: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    });    
}
```

Note: URL is correct, I can get a 200 statuscode, but I would like to handle the `403 access denied`. How do I solve this?

Comment: Did you try open `callUrl` from browser ?

Comment: what exactly do you see in the console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this call is actually made not using an XHR request but via JSONP. ("callback=?" in your URL) - for JSONP requests, status code information are not available. You will need to make sure that always a valid response is send.

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: is there a solution then to get that information. It also doesn't end up in the error(){} function. So why is that?

Comment: JSONP requests are made by inserting `<script>` tags into the document - if the specified urls respond with an error status code, the browser simply ignores that request and the callback that is waiting for the results never gets called (because even if there is content, the corresponding javascript does not get executed). Therefore jQuery has no clue that something didn't work out and can't inform you by calling your error function. - If you need to make JSONP calls, always send 200 Ok and include the actual status information in your response.

Comment: And if you have no control about the response because you're requesting an external API or whatever.. well.. then you're screwed.

Comment: @Niko Are you saying jQuery automagically changes dataType to JSONP when it finds `callback` in the query string?

Comment: Yes: "If the URL includes the string "callback=?" (or similar, as defined by the server-side API), the request is treated as JSONP instead." from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 1):

Reference this to see if you can determine the specific denial. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403 Check the settings of the directory that's throwing the error.